# creation of EPS/PDF figures with LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I have the following problem. While earlier I succeeded to create EPS/PDF figures with LaTeX command (a specific file feynman. sty), and each picture was of a normal size, now something changed in LaTeX in a new version of TexStudio, and the EPS/PDF figure occupies an entire page.
fourpoint.pdf
Using Linux-like style of LaTeX through terminal (which earlier helped to solve this problem on Mac computers) now also does not help.
Thus, the question is -- how to obtain a small-size image in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why not make your epd.pdf figures as independenr figures with the `standalone` class, and include the result via `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Dear Bernard,
If I understand you correctly, you want to say that I need to add the standalone class to preamble? 
From another side, the problem is that earlier I was created figures with LaTeX, but now the result is not satisfactory.
Certainly, creating of figures with some another program with their subsequent inclusion to LaTeX is a good solution. But I would like to create figures with LaTeX.

Comment: No, you don't have to add whatever to the preamble. You just create one independent file per figure, with the standalone class and the relevant packages, and create  autonomous figures in the same directory as the main file. That's the way I work, personally (usually with pstricks and xelatex).

Comment: It is rather hard to guess what you did before or what you are doing now that is changed. Show a small complete example document that shows the problem, then someone can suggest how to correct it, and test their answer.

Comment: Dear Colleagues,
Whether there is a possibility to attach the TEX file which I used to create a picture? The reason is that I used the specific style which I included into the body of the TEX file.

Answer (score 1):

The situation became much more simple.
Actually, after starting the Terminal command as usual, I processed the TEX file (latex *.tex), then converted DVI to PS as usual (dvips *.dvi), and then, used the simple command ps2eps *.ps. And the problem is solved!
By the way, I am grateful to all of you for calling my attention to extra programs for designing Feynman diagrams, for example, https://www.aidansean.com/feynman/.
Thank you very much again!